# setting a constant via promise in run phase - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to set a constant in the run phase? I would need this value set in order to my services to work properly, this is my case.

```
 angular
 .constant('MYCONSTANT', {})
 .factory('myFactory', function($http) {
     return {
         getSomething : getSomething
     };

     function getSomething() {
         return $http.get('myurl');
     }
 })
 .run(function(myFactory, MYCONSTANT) {
     myFactory.getSomething().then(function(response) {
         MYCONSTANT = response;
     });
 });
```

If I console log the value of the constant in the run phase, it has the proper value, however, If I check it into any other service when they are called, it is an empty object.

I wouldn't want to rely on the resolve method exposed by ui-router.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking a constant? What's the point of changing the value of a constant during runtime? Why not just use a factory/service instead?

Comment: actually it is a user information that I need to match on several places, I just want to request the information first time the app loads and then keep it saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      MYCONSTANT = response;
```

just assigns a new value to local `MYCONSTANT` variable, the original object reference is lost in this case. To work as intended it should be

```
      angular.forEach(MYCONSTANT, function (val, key) {
        // if MYCONSTANT is non-empty
        delete MYCONSTANT[key];
      });
      angular.extend(MYCONSTANT, response);
```

Comment: works great but I kind dont understand why it doesnt work as object reference >.<

Comment: @andresmijares25 This is how variables work in JS, there's nothing specific to Angular: `var a = {}; var b = a; b = {}`. `a !== b` here.

Comment: recap, at what point the constant is blank again? I mean into my callback, MYCONSTANT = response; all good... so if I check later MYCONSTANT, when it got blanked again?? am I confused or something? btw, thanks for your time!

Comment: The value of 'MYCONSTANT' `constant` service was an empty object all the time. Injected `MYCONSTANT` is a local variable that contains a reference to the object that was defined with `constant`, it was passed as an argument to `run` function. If this reference is overwritten with `=`, this affects only function's local variable, not anything else out there.